# VBA Excel ascii to hex

Tags: excel, vba, hex, ascii

I am having trouble with ascii to hex conversion with VBA. I need to convert a String, which combines letters and numbers to hex.
However my code converts only about half of the string.

I have in A1 following Sting: BFEBFBFF000406E3

The code I have fills in A6: 42464542464246400000000000000000

I am using http://www.convertstring.com/cs/EncodeDecode/HexDecode to check if it is ok and there it translates as: 42464542464246463030303430364533DA

What do I have wrong please?

```
Sub strg()

Dim strg As String
Dim tmp As String

strg = Worksheets("List1").Range("A1")
Worksheets("List1").Range("A5").Value = strg

tmp = ""
For I = 1 To Len(strg)
  tmp = tmp & hex((Asc(Mid(strg, I, 1))))
Next


Worksheets("List1").Range("A6").Value = tmp

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't the `For Next loop` have a `step 2` so that it reads 2 characters at a time?

Comment: Looks like the string is converted to a Double which truncates the number to 15 digits. Add a quote in front: `.Value = Chr(39) & tmp`

Comment: or put `Worksheets("List1").Range("A6").NumberFormat = "@"` before assigne `tmp` to the cell.

Comment: I think you are referring to the `HexEncode` page.  And when I run it, the result does not include the `DA` at the end.  And, since `tmp` contains the correct result, either of the two options above to write the result as `text` to the cell should work.

Comment: DA in hex is 13 (ASCII carriage return) and 10 (ASCII line feed), so you're picking up the end of line marker from wherever you copied the string that you pasted into that web page.

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets("List1").Range("A6").NumberFormat = "@" & tmp works prefectly, thank you Scott Craner